# How many times would you have to roll a single die on average to reach a sum of at least 30?

Tags: probability, dice

I am primarily asking for what this kind of problem would be called.

Say I have one six-sided die. How many times on average would I have to roll it in order to have a sum of at least 30?

Doing some googling, the closest I have found was a geometric distribution. But I am unsure if that is strictly for pass/fail scenarios (such as flipping a coin or drawing a name out of a hat).

The closest I can get is that it will take no more than 30 tries (at a $1/6^30$ chance) and no less than 5 tries (at a $1/6^5$ chance). My problem arises when I think about the number of possible ways to get 6 tries. It would be easy if each die had 2 outcomes, but each one has 6, and many combinations can accomplish this. I don't even know where to begin figuring out how many combinations exist outside of counting (which would take hours).

EDIT: So I found this [Help with the Probabilty of Rolling Two Ten-Sided Dice Multiple Times Until 100 is Reached](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733942/help-with-the-probabilty-of-rolling-two-ten-sided-dice-multiple-times-until-100?rq=1)

This is very much what this problem is, but it doesn't mention what the process is called. Which in the end is what my main question is.

Comment: "This is very much what this problem is" Sorry but I fail to see where they treat your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A standard way to solve this is to consider simultaneously the mean number of rolls $t_n$ needed to reach $n$ for every nonnegative integer $n$ (and to remember at the end that the OP is asking for $t_{30}$). So, let us do that...

For every $n\leqslant0$, $t_n=0$. For every $n\geqslant1$, considering the result of the first roll, one sees that
$$t_n=1+\frac16\sum_{k=1}^6t_{n-k}
$$
Thus, the series $$T(s)=\sum_nt_ns^n$$ solves
$$T(s)=\frac s{1-s}+\frac16\sum_{k=1}^6s^kT(s)$$ from which it follows that
$$T(s)=\frac{6s}{(1-s)\left(6-\sum\limits_{k=1}^6s^k\right)}=\frac{6s}{6-7s+s^7}$$
To extract the coefficient $t_{30}=[s^{30}]T(s)$ of $s^{30}$ in $T(s)$, rewrite this as
$$T(s)=s\left(1-rs\left(1-\frac t7\right)\right)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ns^{n+1}\left(1-\frac t7\right)^n$$
where $$r=\frac76\qquad t=s^6$$
hence
$$[s^{30}]T(s)=\sum_{k=0}^4r^{5+6k}[t^{4-k}]\left(1-\frac t7\right)^{5+6k}$$
or, equivalently,
$$[s^{30}]T(s)=\sum_{k=0}^46^{-5-6k}[t^{4-k}]\left(7-t\right)^{5+6k}=\frac7{6^5}\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^kr^{6k}{5+6k\choose4-k}$$
that is,
$$t_{30}=\frac7{6^5}\left(5-165r^6+136r^{12}-23r^{18}+r^{24}\right)
$$
which can be "simplified" into the exact result $$t_{30}=
\frac{333366007330230566034343}{36845653286788892983296}$$ with a numerical approximation $$t_{30}\approx
9.047634594384022902065997942672796588425278684184104625$$

---

**Edit:** To get some estimates of $t_n$ when $n\to\infty$, note that $$T(s)=\frac s{(1-s)^2Q(s)}$$ where $$Q(s)=\frac16(6+5s+4s^2+3s^3+2s^4+s^5)$$ Furthermore,  $(1-s)Q(s)=1-\frac16\sum\limits_{k=1}^6s^k$ has no zero in the closed unit disk except the simple zero $s=1$ hence $Q(s)$ has no zero in the closed unit disk. This implies that $$T(s)=\frac a{(1-s)^2}+\frac b{1-s}+R(s)$$ for some given $(a,b)$ and some rational fraction $R(s)=\sum\limits_nr_ns^n$ with no pole in the closed unit disk. Then, there exists some finite $c$ and some $\varrho$ in $(0,1)$ such that,  for every $n$, $$|r_n|\leqslant c\varrho^n$$ This yields, again for every $n$, $$|t_n-a(n+1)-b|=|r_n|\leqslant c\varrho^n$$ Equivalently, $$t_n=an+(a+b)+O(\varrho^n)$$ To identify $(a,b)$, note that $$(1-s)^2T(s)=a+b(1-s)+(1-s)^2R(s)$$ hence $$a=\left.(1-s)^2T(s)\right|_{s=1}=\frac1{Q(1)}$$ and $$b=-\left.\frac d{ds}[(1-s)^2T(s)]\right|_{s=1}=-\frac1{Q(1)}+\frac{Q'(1)}{Q(1)^2}$$ or, equivalently, $$a+b=\frac{Q'(1)}{Q(1)^2}$$
Finally, $Q(1)=\frac72$ and $Q'(1)=\frac{35}6$ hence $a=\frac27$ and $a+b=\frac{10}{21}$, which implies
$$t_n=\frac27n+\frac{10}{21}+O(\varrho^n)$$
**Edit-edit:** More generally, throwing repeatedly a "die" producing a random number of points distributed like $X$, following the same route, one gets
$a=E(X)$ and $a+b=Q'(1)/E(X)^2$ with $Q'(1)=\frac12E(X(X-1))$, hence, for some $\varrho_X$ in $(0,1)$ depending on the distribution of $X$, $$t_n=\frac1{E(X)}n+\frac{E(X(X-1))}{2E(X)^2}+O(\varrho_X^n)$$

Comment: Nice answer, +1! \\ Do you reckon that, replacing $30$ by $M$ you could get a nice, tractable, limiting result? My (significantly less complete) answer shows that asymptotically it's $\tfrac27 M + \mathcal O(1)$, and the answer to [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101264] shows that (in your $t_M$ notation) $$\bigl| t_M - \tfrac27 (M + \tfrac83) \bigr| \to 0 \quad \text{as $M \to \infty$}.$$ Do you think your method would be able to give that in a tractable way?

Comment: @SamT Yes, please see edit. Note that the page you link to  seems unavailable and that the result in it, as you transcribe it, differs from the one I get by a shift $n\to n+1$ (or $M\to M+1$...) since $\frac27+\frac{10}{21}$ (my result) is also $\frac27\cdot\frac83=\frac{16}{21}$ (the one in your comment). Finally, I hope the way to compute the optimal value of $\varrho$, if need be, is clear from my edit.

Comment: Dude, you are one analytic/probabilistic machine! I don't know enough about analysis to know why such a $c$ and $\varrho$ exist in the first place; do you have a reference I can read? \\ Regarding the link, just take the final square bracket ] off -- for some reason it's put that in the link. Moreover, I did get the shift wrong (silly calculation error), and your answer of $10/21$ is correct.

Comment: The geometric control follows from the fact that $Q(s)$ is a polynomial with no root in the unit disk hence $$Q(s)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^5(1-\alpha_ks)$$ for some $|\alpha_k|<1$. Thus, the decomposition in simple elements of $T(s)$ reads $$T(s)=\frac a{(1-s)^2}+\frac b{1-s}+\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{\beta_k}{1-\alpha_k s}$$ that is, $$R(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^5\beta_k\alpha_k^ns^n$$ Thus, the bound in my Edit holds with $$c=\sum_{k=1}^5|\beta_k|\qquad\varrho=\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant 5}|\alpha_k|$$ (This is the idea if the $\alpha_k$s are distinct, otherwise the result remains true.)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I like this generating function/series approach. I must confess it's not the style of proof that I tend to employ... but I'm beginning to feel that I should employ it more often!

Comment: @Did: Instructive answer. Very nice. (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks. Be aware though, that everything in this approach is well known... :-)

Comment: @Did: Yes, I'm aware of it. :-) But I also like this *kind* of presentation and I think I will incorporate some aspects when providing answers for similar questions.

Answer (score 4):

Let's replace the target "$30$" with a general target $M$.
Let $X_n$ denote the 'score' after $n$ throws; define $Y_n = X_n - \tfrac72 n$.
Note that $E(Y_n) = 0$, and moreover $E(Y_n \mid Y_{n-1}) = 0$, so it is a martingale.
Let
$$ \tau = \inf\{ n \ge 0 \mid X_n \ge M \} = \inf\{ n \ge 0 \mid Y_n \ge M - \tfrac72 n \}. $$
Then $\tau$ is a stopping time for $Y$, and so by the optional stopping theorem $E(Y_\tau) = Y_0 = 0$.
(Here $\tau$ is deterministically bounded by $M$, and so this is the easy case for OST.)
In particular,
$$ E(Y_\tau) = 0 \iff E(\tau) = \tfrac27 E(X_\tau). $$
A key point is that while $X_\tau \ge M$, we don't necessarily have equality.
Of course, $X_\tau \in [M,M+5]$, and so
$$ E(\tau) \in \bigl[ \tfrac27M, \tfrac27(M+5) \bigr], $$
and interval of width $10/7$. If you imagine $M \to \infty$, this means that we know $E(\tau)$ is linear in $M$ (and even know the constant, $\tfrac27$) and our estimate is $\mathcal O(1)$ off.

This is as far as I am able to get. It is not clear to me what the distribution of $X_\tau$ is. (Note that one only needs to know its mean.)

---

**Update.** I was interested by this, and posted a very related question: [Distribution at First Time a Sum Reaches a Threshold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101264/distribution-at-first-time-a-sum-reaches-a-threshold). The answer given there (not by me, unfortunately!) gives the limiting distribution of $X_\tau$, in a simple form from which it is easy to calculate the mean (in the limit $M \to \infty$).
Using this question/answer, and a little bit of algebra, one finds that the answer in question is that
$$ E(\tau) = \tfrac27 M + \tfrac{10}{21} + o(1). $$

The answer also gives an iterative solution for any $M$, but involves working out a large power of a matrix.

Comment: Not $E(\tau) = \tfrac27 M + \tfrac{10}{21}$ but $E(\tau) = \tfrac27 M + \tfrac{10}{21}+o(1)$.

Comment: Oops, thank you! If you check the link, you'll see the $o(1)$ term is there (implicitly, since $M \to \infty$ is considered). Thanks!

Comment: I know. $ $ $ $

Comment: "The answer given there (not by me, unfortunately!) gives the distribution of , in a simple form from which it is easy to calculate the mean" No it does not give it "in a simple form from which it is easy to calculate the mean".

Comment: I meant "in the limit $M \to \infty$" (hence the $o(1)$ term). I've made this explicit

Answer (score 0):

The generating function for the distribution of sums when rolling $k$ six sided dice is
$$
\left(\frac{x}6+\frac{x^2}6+\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^4}6+\frac{x^5}6+\frac{x^6}6\right)^k=\left(\frac{x-x^7}{6(1-x)}\right)^k
$$
The probability that roll $k$ will put the total to $n$ or greater is, assuming we've made $k-1$ rolls, the probability that the total is $n-1$, plus $\frac56$ of the probability that the total is $n-2$, plus $\frac46$ of the probability that the total is $n-3$, plus $\frac36$ of the probability that the total is $n-4$, plus $\frac26$ of the probability that the total is $n-5$, plus $\frac16$ of the probability that the total is $n-6$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left[x^n\right]\left(x+\frac56x^2+\frac46x^3+\frac36x^4+\frac26x^5+\frac16x^6\right)\left(\frac{x^7-x}{6(x-1)}\right)^{k-1}\\
&=\left[x^n\right]\frac{x-\frac76x^2+\frac16x^8}{(1-x)^2}\left(\frac{x^7-x}{6(x-1)}\right)^{k-1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the generating function for the average number of rolls to total $n$ or more is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x-\frac76x^2+\frac16x^8}{(1-x)^2}k\left(\frac{x^7-x}{6(x-1)}\right)^{k-1}
&=\frac{x-\frac76x^2+\frac16x^8}{(1-x)^2}\frac1{\left(1-\frac{x^7-x}{6(x-1)}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{x-\frac76x^2+\frac16x^8}{(1-x)^2}\left(\frac{1-x}{1-\frac76x+\frac16x^7}\right)^2\\[12pt]
&=\frac{x}{1-\frac76x+\frac16x^7}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Recursion to Compute Coefficients**

If we set
$$
\frac{x}{1-\frac76x+\frac16x^7}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_nx^n}{6^{n-1}}
$$
then we get the recursion
$$
a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{}
7^{n-1}&\text{if }1\le n\le7\\
7\,a_{n-1}-46656\,a_{n-7}&\text{if }n\gt7
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thus to answer the question,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{30}}{6^{29}}
&=\frac{333366007330230566034343}{36845653286788892983296}\\[6pt]
&\doteq9.0476345943840229021
\end{align}
$$

---

**Power Series to Compute Coefficients**
$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^n\right]\frac{x}{1-\frac76x+\frac16x^7}
&=\left[x^{n-1}\right]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac76x-\frac16x^7\right)^k\\
&=\left[x^{n-1}\right]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(\frac76\right)^{k-j}x^{k-j}\left(-\frac16\right)^jx^{7j}\\
&=\left[x^{n-1}\right]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=j}^\infty\binom{k}{j}\left(\frac76\right)^{k-j}x^{k-j}\left(-\frac16\right)^jx^{7j}\\
&=\left[x^{n-1}\right]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+j}{j}\left(\frac76\right)^kx^k\left(-\frac16\right)^jx^{7j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+j}{j}\left(\frac76\right)^k\left(-\frac16\right)^j[k+7j=n-1]\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}7\right\rfloor}\binom{n-6j-1}{j}\left(\frac76\right)^{n-7j-1}\left(-\frac16\right)^j\\
\end{align}
$$
For $n=30$, this gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\textstyle\binom{29}{0}\left(\frac76\right)^{29}-\binom{23}{1}\left(\frac76\right)^{22}\left(\frac16\right)^1+\binom{17}{2}\left(\frac76\right)^{15}\left(\frac16\right)^2-\binom{11}{3}\left(\frac76\right)^8\left(\frac16\right)^3+\binom{5}{4}\left(\frac76\right)^1\left(\frac16\right)^4\\[6pt]
&=\textstyle\frac1{6^{29}}\left(\binom{29}{0}7^{29}-\binom{23}{1}7^{22}6^6+\binom{17}{2}7^{15}6^{12}-\binom{11}{3}7^86^{18}+\binom{5}{4}7^16^{24}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{333366007330230566034343}{36845653286788892983296}\\[9pt]
&\doteq9.0476345943840229021
\end{align}
$$