# Distribution at First Time a Sum Reaches a Threshold

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, martingales

Consider the following problem.
Roll a die many times, and stop when the total exceeds $M$, for some prescribed threshold $M$.
Call this time $\tau$, and call the running score after $n$ rolls $X_n$.

> What is the distribution of $X_\tau$?

Of course $X_\tau \in [M,M+5]$. However, I can get little beyond this.
Moreover, for small $M$ the distribution should be very sensitive, and I doubt have a nice form. However, if I define $X'_\tau = X_\tau - M$, then it seems to me that $X'_\tau$ should have a limiting distribution at $M \to \infty$.

---

**Extra comments.** $\quad$
Note that there are various related questions here on maths.SE, but these (as far as I have seen) are about determining $\tau$, in particular its expectation, $E(\tau)$.

Also, one can solve for $E(\tau)$ directly. If I write $k_M$ for $E(\tau)$ with threshold $M$, then
$$ \textstyle k_M = \tfrac16 \sum_{j=1}^6 k_{M-j} + 1, $$
and writing $\ell_M = k_M - k_{M-1}$ we get
$$ \textstyle \ell_M = \tfrac16 \sum_{j=1}^6 \ell_{M-j}. $$
In principle, by trying the solution $\ell_r = r^\lambda$ and solving
$$ 6 \lambda^6 - \lambda^5 - \lambda^4 - \lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 = 0, $$
(see [this WolframAlpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B6x%5E6%20-%20x%5E5%20-%20x%5E4%20-%20x%5E3%20-%20x%5E2%20-%20x%20-%201,%20x%5D)), and calculating some initial conditions by hand, then one can find $k_M = E(\tau)$.
Note that this would involve finding six initial conditions and solving a set of six simultaneous equations. This is only for the $\ell$-s; one then needs to convert this into the $k$-s.
This does not sound like fun to me! =P

By a simple martingale argument---$(X_n - \tfrac72n)_{n\ge0}$ is a martingale, and $\tau$ is a deterministically bounded stopping time---from this one immediately gets $E(X_\tau) = \tfrac27 E(\tau)$ (for any $M$).

Comment: Does hitting $M$ exactly count as being done; or do you have to have a sum strictly greater than $M$?

Comment: Yes, hitting $M$ counts as being done; this is why $X_\tau$ can be equal to $M$ (and not $M+6$). However, my title says *exceeds*, so I see where your confusion lies!---changed now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p^M_i$ be the probability that $X_{\tau(M)}=M+i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,5$, and $p^M$ denote the column vector of these six values.

You can compute $p_M$ from $p_{M-1}$ as follows. There are two ways to achieve a final value of $M+i$; either the first time that you value at or above $M-1$ you reach is $(M-1)+(i+1)$, or the first value at or above $M-1$ you reach is $M-1$, and then from there you jump immediately to $M+i$. Therefore,
$$
p_i^M=\begin{cases}p^{M-1}_{i+1}+\frac16 p^{M-1}_0 & i<5\\\frac16p_0^{M-1} & i=5\end{cases}
$$
This can be written as a matrix equation:
$$
p^M=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac16 & 1 & \\
\frac16 &0  & 1 &\\
\frac16 & 0&0 & 1 &\\
\frac16 &  0&0&0& 1 &\\
\frac16 &  0&0&0&0& 1 \\
\frac16 &  0&0  &0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}p^{M-1}
$$
with zeroes above the super-diagonal. 
Letting $A$ be the above matrix, then this proves $$p^M=A^Mp^0,$$ where $p^0$ is a vector whose first entry is $1$ and whose other entries are zero.

The limiting distribution $p$ will satisfy $p=Ap$. This means that $p_i=p_{i+1}+\frac16p_0$, so that $p$ is an arithmetic progression with difference $-\frac16p_0$. A little thought shows that this implies
$$
p=\left(\frac{6}{21},\frac{5}{21},\frac{4}{21},\frac{3}{21},\frac{2}{21},\frac{1}{21}\right)^T.
$$

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't think of writing $M+i = (M-1) + (i+1)$. (To be honest, I really should have!) It's clear what to do if you hit $M-1$, but if one is at $M-3$, say, it was less clear to me. I now feel kinda stupid not having got that, but it's always easy once you see a solution---doesn't mean it was easy to find the solution! =P

Comment: Also, while the whole argument was in the second paragraph, thanks for writing out the details of the rest so that I didn't have to go through them myself =P

Comment: Also, it appears to me that this should be pretty easy to generalise, yes? If one has a "die" that gives output $X$ (discrete), simply replace the column of $\tfrac16$s with the appropriate distribution? One then just solves the related $p = Ap$ with this new column, which again is pretty easy due to the nature of the matrix. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SamT That's right! The limiting distribution should be the reverse cumulative sums of the pmf of X, renormalized to be a probability distribution.

Comment: That's a really cool result, actually! :)

Comment: @MikeEarnest - inspired by your answer, i came up with a different proof.  do you think it is valid?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answer from @MikeEarnest, I wonder if the following alternate proof is valid, for the limiting case?  This proof has the advantage(?) of less algebra, and hopefully more intuition into *why* the distribution is 6:5:4:3:2:1.

Imagine you keep rolling forever.  A number is *reached* if it is the sum at some point in time, otherwise it is *skipped*.  Clearly in the limit, all numbers have the same probability $q$ of being reached.  (This follows from ergodicity, right?  In fact, ergodicity would suggest $q = {1 \over 3.5}$, but we don't need its exactly value for now.)

Now consider the interval of interest, $X_\tau \in [M, M+5]$:

- $X_\tau = M+5$ iff $M-1$ is reached and the next roll is $6$.  This happens with probability $q/6$.
- $X_\tau = M+4$ iff (a) $M-1$ is reached and the next roll is $5$, or, (b) $M-2$ is reached and the next roll is $6$.  So this happens with probability $2q/6$.

  - Note that the case of reaching $M-2$, then rolling $1$ to reach $M-1$, then rolling $5$ to reach $M+4$, is included in (a) but not in (b), so we did not double-count.
- Similarly, $X_\tau = M+3, M+2, M+1, M$ with probabilities $3q/6, 4q/6, 5q/6, 6q/6$ respectively.

Since these 6 possibilities are exhaustive, we have
$$(1+2+3+4+5+6)q/6 = 1 \implies q = {6 \over 21} = {1 \over 3.5}$$ as I originally suspected; in particular, this implies that
$$P(X_\tau = M + j) = (6-j)q/6 = (6-j)/21,$$
agreeing with Mike's answer.

Comment: Interesting! I hope you don't mind, but I added one line to your answer; you hadn't explicitly repeated what the distribution was, so I thought that would be helpful. \\ But yes, I'm pretty sure that argument is valid -- it's a bit late (11pm) for me to think about it now, but I'll just check tomorrow that the ergodicity argument is fine

Comment: @SamT you edit contains a typo :) (which i fixed) but is otherwise good.  anyway, this approach _assumes_ the "obvious" fact that in the limit every large number is reached with same prob $q$.  Under this assumption the proof is valid (I think), but proving this "obvious" assumption would require bringing in heavier machinery.  But hopefully this gives more insight into _why_ the distribution is 6:5:4:3:2:1.

Comment: Yes, it definitely does give insight -- and for a 'roll distribution $R$' (ie more general than just $\text{Uniform}(1,...,6)$), it does generalise (although general distributions could get messy to write out). Definitely a +1!

Comment: hmm, @SamT interesting observation re: a general roll distribution $R$.  E.g. $R=\{1,10,27\}$ would be pretty tedious to write out and the distribution of $X_\tau \in [M, M+26]$ would also be pretty interesting.  As long as the possible $R$ values have  $gcd = 1$, the "obvious" ergodic assumption should hold.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right: tedious, but the method would certainly work. And good shout on the $\text{gcd}$!